# How to compare distances

Tags: netlogo

I am simulating a mouse trapped in a circular pond with a cat roaming the outside of the pond. The mouse always moves 180 degrees away from the cat, and the cat is SUPPOSED to get as close to the mouse as it can from the outside.

However, right now the cat just moves around clockwise until the mouse is out of the pond and has reached the wall. THEN it changes direction going counter-clockwise.

I want the code to basically compare the distance before and after the cat moves; if the distance to the mouse is more, than it needs to turn around, if the distance to the mouse is less, that means it's getting closer and should keep going that way.

My code is below:

```
    to go

      mouse-movement
      cat-movement

    end
```

```
    to cat-movement 

      ask turtle 0   

      [

        pen-down

        set cprevious-patch-distance distance turtle 1

        move-along-circle radius

        set ccurrent-patch-distance distance turtle 1

      ]

    end
```

```
    to move-along-circle [r]

      ifelse

       ccurrent-patch-distance < cprevious-patch-distance 

       [

        fd (pi * r / 180) * (speed / 50)

        rt speed / 50

       ]

       [

        fd (pi * r / 180) * (speed / 50) * -1

        rt speed / 50 * -1

       ]
    end
```

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you're asking here. Is turtle 0 the cat and turtle 1 the mouse? Also, have you tried printing out the values of ccurrent-patch-distance and cprevious-patch-distance to see what's happening?